# If I double all feature values in sample with class 1, will class 1 have a weight of 2?

Tags: classification

In a classification problem, I want to know how to manually manipulate the data to weight the classes without using the features provided by the machine learning library. For example, if I double all feature values in sample with class 1, will class 1 have a weight of 2?

If there is a way to do this, I would like to know if it can be applied to non-neural models.